# Segmentation Fault programación dinamica

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de comprender la programación dinamica. Quiero calcular el costo optimo de mover de un edificio a otro. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar de el por que me podrá estar dando el error de segmentación.

Gracias!

```
unsigned calcularCosto( const std::vector<unsigned> edificioAcosto, 
const std::vector<unsigned> edificioBcosto, unsigned costoDeMover)
{
    int edificioAsize = edificioA.size();
    unsigned sol[2][4]; //unsigned sol[2][edificioAsize] con esto da Werro
    int j = 0;
    sol[0][0] = edificioAcosto[0];
    sol[1][0] = edificioBcosto[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < edificioAsize; i++)
    {
        j=0;
        sol[j][i] = std::min(sol[j][i-1] + edificioAcosto[i], sol[j+1][i-1] + edificioAcosto[i] + costoDeMover);
        j++;
        sol[j][i] = std::min(sol[j][i-1] + edificioBcosto[i], sol[j-1][i-1] + edificioBcosto[i] + costoDeMover);

        
    }
    return sol[1][edificioAsize-1]; 
}


//Esta prueba la pasa sin problema pero si intento hacer una prueba mas
//grande de segmenta.

    TEST(unaPrueba, pruebaCorta)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned> edificioAcosto = {1, 3, 20, 20};
        std::vector<unsigned> edificioBcosto = {50, 20, 2, 4};


        EXPECT_TRUE( 20 == calcularCost( edificioAcosto, edificioBcosto, 10 ) );
    }
```

Comment: Casi siempre un segfault es un puntero que apunta a donde no debe, o un acceso a un array fuera de límites. Revisa que el índice `i` no exceda nunca el valor 7 (pues ese es el último índice válido para el array `sol`), y que `edificioAcosto` también tenga 8 elementos. Ops... y ahora que me fijo, intentas acceder a un índice `[i+1]` e  `[i-1]`. Seguro que por ahí vienen los problemas, cuando `i`  es cero ó 7.

Comment: Tienes razon un problema estaba en mi array sol. si la bajo a sol[2][4] me pasa un test y falla los demas. Pero si trato de usar sol[2][edificioA.size()] me marca ahora un Werror.

Comment: `sol[j][i] = std::min(sol[j][i-1]` ... si inicializas `i=0`, te sales fuera del espacio usado. Pero, por favor, presenta un [mcve] para poder darte una respuesta segura.

Comment: @Juanjo puse una prueba que es la que pasa